# Comparing multiple fields in two datasets to return a 3rd value

Tags: reporting-services

I am in report builder and I have my primary dataset that is from a SQL database, I also then created a second dataset (enter data). I need to compare 2 fields from each dataset to retrieve the correct value from the 2nd dataset and populate a column on my report. I have tried the IIF statements and Lookup statements but I keep getting the error "report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset".

I have a attached a screenshot of what I am trying to do....

The IIF statement I tried to use..  If Acctnum and prodid = each other return IncodeNumber

```
=IIF((Fields!AcctNum.Value=Fields!AcctNum.Value, "IncodeAccount") AND
   (Fields!ProdId.Value =Fields!ProdId.Value, "IncodeAccount")),(Fields!IncodeNumber.Value, "IncodeAccount"),"True")
```

See code in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LOOKUP()`. The problem with `LOOKUP()` is that is can only compare a single value from each dataset. However, we can easily get around this issue by concatenating the two values you need to compare.

**Note:** This assumes the expression will be in a tablix that is bound to your first dataset and that `IncodeAccount` is your second dataset - the values you want to lookup. If this is not the case just adjust the expression accordingly

So for you, you probably need to do something like this..

```
=LOOKUP(
        Fields!AcctNum.Value & "||" & Fields!ProdId.Value, 
        Fields!AcctNum.Value & "||" & Fields!ProdId.Value,
        Fields!IncodeNumber.Value,
        "IncodeAccount"
       )
```

I've used two pipe symbols to join the values to avoid incorrect matches being found. e.g. Account 123 and product ID 4567 would incorrectly match to Account 1234 and product ID 567 as they would both be 1234567 when joined. By using the `||` the match would be `123||4567` and `1234||567` respectively.

You *may* need to convert the values to string using `CStr()`

---

**Alternative approach**

---

If you are going to do this 'join' multiple times in the same dataset then you could add a calculated column to the dataset that concatenates the two columns. Then you can use this single field in the lookup which will make things a little simpler.

Or, you could do this concatenation in a database view which would make things even easier.